# How to format bigger numbers in android studio

Tags: java, number-formatting

I've been making an idle game (similar like cookie clicker) and I can't figure out how to format a number that is always changing. Let's say a number reaches 1 billion. It doesn't print it out like that but it rather says 1000 M.

How do I format it so it always shows if it's a million, billion, trillion all the way till nonillion

```
allBuildingCps = building1cps + building2cps + building3cps +
                    building4cps + building5cps + building6cps +
                    building7cps + building8cps + building9cps +
                    building10cps;

            String CpsAll = "";
            if (Math.abs(allBuildingCps / 1000000) >= 1)
            {
                CpsAll = (allBuildingCps / 1000000) + "m";
            } else if (Math.abs(allBuildingCps / 1000000000) > 1)
            {
                CpsAll = (allBuildingCps / 1000000000) + "b";
            }

            cps.setText(CpsAll + " CPS");
```

Comment: Reverse your if condition, check for billion first, then million. Your code does not reach to condition where you are checking for billion.

Comment: for readability, I would recommend replacing `Math.abs(allBuildingCps / 1000000) >= 1` with Math.abs(allBuildingCps)>=1000000

Comment: @jnrdn001 Thanks for the solution. I don't know how I missed that.